# using the value of <TD> that gets populated using JavaScript in php

Tags: javascript, php

here are the code snippets for what I'm working on:

function to do the math (*this part works*)

```
function calcTotal(){
    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = '';
    var wages = new Number(document.getElementById('wagestotal').innerHTML);
    var milage = new Number(document.getElementById('milagetotal').innerHTML);
    var travel = new Number(document.getElementById('travel').value);
    var lodging = new Number(document.getElementById('lodging').value);
    var food = new Number(document.getElementById('food').value);
    var office = new Number(document.getElementById('office').value);
    var other = new Number(document.getElementById('other').value);
    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = ((wages + milage + travel + lodging + food + office + other).toFixed(2));
}
```

Form section in question: (*this part displays correctly*)

```
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Grand Total:</td>
        <td>=</td>
        <td id="total"></td>
    </tr>
    </font>
</table>
```

php section to populate database

```
$total = trim($_POST['total']);
```

When the form gets submitted the information gets put in a database using php. It all works except the Grand Total. All the fields except the Grand total are text input fields, and get populated in the database without any issues. The "Grand Total" however does not get populated in the database. I'm assuming it has something to do with the Grand total being displayed in `<td id="total"></td>` I've tried some other ways to make this work with no luck.

How do I get the value displayed in `<td id="total"></td>` assigned to a php variable?

Comment: "total" should be computed again in php, otherwise the user is able to send you fake total value.

Comment: To your question - the simplest solution would be <td><input readonly name="total" id="total" /></td>

Comment: I'm not worried about people giving fake totals. at least not right now.  I tried <td><input readonly name="total" id="total" /></td> The total doesn't display on the page, and it doesn't make it to the database either.

Comment: You must use "value" instead of "innerHTML" to populate it in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

For example, With an hidden field

Function do the Math :

```
  var total = ((wages + milage + travel + lodging + food + office + other).toFixed(2));
  document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total;
  document.getElementById('totalInfo').value = total;
}
```

Form section in question:

```
<td id="totalInfo"></td>
</tr>
</font>
 <input type="hidden" name="total" id="total" value="" />
```

But has said  Roman Hocke, "total" should be computed again in php, otherwise the user is able to send you fake total value